# Tomee WebContext not releasing CreationalContexts

Tags: java, memory, apache-tomee, openejb

I'm experiencing a quite aggressive memory leak using Tomee, Apache Open Web Beans and JSF.

The following code in `org.apache.openejb.core.WebContext` is continually adding elements every time we navigate to a page but never removes them:

```
if (webBeansContext != null) {
    final InjectionTargetBean<Object> bean = InjectionTargetBean.class.cast(beanDefinition);
    bean.getInjectionTarget().inject(beanInstance, creationalContext);

    creatonalContexts.put(beanInstance, creationalContext);
}
```

Resulting in a massive map of JSF Objects and their relating CreationalContext which is never garbage collected:

[image: creationContext map]

Ultimately this is causing the server to run out of memory and fall over.  Has anybody encountered this?

Comment: Which (released) version of OpenEJB/TomEE did you use to find this behaviour?

Comment: Tomee 1.7.2.  I realised that we had the (Majorra) implementation of JSf as a `runtime` rather than `provided` dependency so it was included in the lib of the war file.  Removing this dependency and relying on the implementation in Tomee lib resolved this memory leak, although I'm not sure why (possibly due to the default injection scope).